# How often to check credit card statement

Tags: credit-card

How often should a person check their credit card statement to make sure that they don't fall victim to a wrong charge or cc fraud?

Comment: How do you check? Online? Do you get a printout every week or month from the bank?

Comment: Not a credit card per-say, but I got a text alert a few weekends ago when my debit card was physically swiped in a different state and my debit card was in my pocket.

Answer (score 11):

You are not "required" to check at all, except for the physical statement you receive each month. (Or online if you opted for paperless). That's when the clock starts for you to report fraudulent charges.

That said, if you tend to use a high percent of the card's credit line, you should probably check more frequently, if only to avoid hitting the limit.

Note, the card might offer a feature that alerts you, via email or text, if a charge is made with the card not present. When I charge something via phone or on line, I get an instant alert for these transactions. This might help put your mind at ease.

Comment: This. I just recently turned on text message alerts for one of my credit cards. Since they always come from the same number I saved it as a contact named "Citi CC Alerts". Now I can just open the message history on my phone and instantly see all of my recent charges without having to look at the statement. It's also cool at restaurants to make sure that the tip amount didn't get entered in wrong, since I get the alert approximately 1 second after my card is run.

Comment: "Card not present" alerts are a great idea for monitoring in general, and especially for fraud monitoring. Although, some fraud methods will not show as "card not present." If you have the capability to trigger off all non-chip transactions, that would catch even more potential fraud.

Comment: Text alerts? Giving the CC company or bank your cell number further increases your attack surface. Please search SIM hijacking. I get paper receipts for all transactions, check them immediately and reconcile regularly. Checking my account at the bank's site recently I saw a transaction from a web site that had not been used in years, and immediately had my card canceled.  I used to check monthly to reconcile my account, but now check at least daily. Do not expect the bank to reimburse you if they or anyone else is hacked. Many stories about that in the Canadian news in the last several weeks.

Answer (score 9):

At the very least, you should look over each statement each month as you receive it. You technically have an unlimited amount of time to dispute fraudulent transactions, but you have $0 liability if you do so within two billing cycles. For other disputes, you have 60 days (which would be roughly equivalent to two billing cycles anyway).

[Valuepenguin.com](https://www.valuepenguin.com/disputing-credit-card-purchases) has some more info, and the following chart:

[image]

Although, if you are running a monthly budget (which you should be...) it would be better to look over all transactions, credit card and otherwise, at least a couple times a month. That way you know exactly where your money is going and will spot problems even sooner.